# Android - Hide/Show Fragment showing the wrong fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the first time that I change the visibility of the fragments in my app, the fragment showed isn`t the fragment that I set to show.

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/act_main_frag_top_bar"
    class="br.com.myapp.fragments.TopBarFragment"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/act_main_frag_toolbar"
    class="br.com.myapp.fragments.ToolbarFragment"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<!-- Tabs -->    
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/act_main_frag_twitter"
    class="br.com.myapp.fragments.TwitterFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/act_main_frag_facebook"
    class="br.com.myapp.fragments.FacebookFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/act_main_frag_tv_show"
    class="br.com.myapp.fragments.TVShowFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/act_main_frag_info"
    class="br.com.bluepen.mixtv.fragments.InfoFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/act_main_frag_streaming"
    class="br.com.myapp.fragments.StreamingFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And myActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mStreamingFrag = (StreamingFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_main_frag_streaming);
    mFacebookFrag = (FacebookFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_main_frag_facebook);
    mTwitterFrag = (TwitterFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_main_frag_twitter);
    mTVShowFrag = (TVShowFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_main_frag_tv_show);
    mInfoFrag = (InfoFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_main_frag_info);
    mToolbar = (ToolbarFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_main_frag_toolbar);
    mToolbar.setListener(this);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.show(mStreamingFrag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

After the onCreate, the fragment getting showed is the TwitterFragment, and not the StreamingFragment that I set to show in the final of the onCreate method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the problem, I changed to hide all the fragments in the onCreate. Aparentelly the android:visibility="gone" in the xml didn`t do this.

Here is the code of the onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    mStreamingFrag = (StreamingFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_main_frag_streaming);
    transaction.show(mStreamingFrag);
    mFacebookFrag = (FacebookFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_main_frag_facebook);
    transaction.hide(mFacebookFrag);
    mTwitterFrag = (TwitterFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_main_frag_twitter);
    transaction.hide(mTwitterFrag);
    mTVShowFrag = (TVShowFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_main_frag_tv_show);
    transaction.hide(mTVShowFrag);
    mInfoFrag = (InfoFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.act_main_frag_info);
    transaction.hide(mInfoFrag);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

I don`t know if I can set the fragment to hide in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with 2 buttons (button1 and button2), when i had to hide the first button , the 2nd was hiding and the first was doing nothing... Everything i've done was CTRL+C the xml and CTRL+V back... Hope it works...

Comment: I find the problem. Check my answer bellow.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt' see that before... It's almost what I was talking about! :-)